# XCode 7.3 requires development certificate even if not referenced/used?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, provisioning-profile

It seems that `XCode` requires a development certificate even if all of the target configurations reference distribution certificates.

If not present, it reports an error

> Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the
>   provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“iOS Team
>   Provisioning Profile: *.

Is this a feature? If so, can someone explain the rationale?

If this is a bug, is it new with 7.3?

Comment: Can you post screen shot

Comment: I am working on 7.3 buy dint faced issue like this

Comment: You certainly do not need a development profile, although you really should have one.  You need a dev profile to debug, and at some point you will want to debug your code.  However, I think you actually have your build settings set up incorrectly.  Can you send a screenshot of your build settings on your project, specifically the "Code Signing" section